# Can we integrate Google Analytics with android library project

Tags: android, google-analytics

This is just a library project that is going to be distributed as an aar file. When an app is made using this library, I want to be able to see the device info and stuff in my Google Analytics Dashboard.

I however don't want the app developer to add anything to his code to provide me these analytics.

I wanna know if such a thing is possible. I could'nt find a solid answer to this question in any website.